# How do rate gyros and other sensors send information to the flight control computer in an F-16?

Tags: flight-controls, avionics, f-16, sensors

How do rate gyros and other sensors send information to the flight control computer in an F-16? I mean is it a hardwired communication or it is done through a bus? If by bus, what is the bus called?

I have read some articles about A-Mux. Is it the bus that the gyros transmit data through? I have the same question about the actuators. How does the flight control computer send information to the actuators? By bus or hard-wired? If you have references, that will be appreciated.

Comment: Modern rate gyros often have digital interfaces. The F-16 has had both analog and digital flight controls and the interfaces are likely to be significantly different within each type.

Comment: I've never heard of A-Mux in respect to aviation. Any links to relevant articles?

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19830004825.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The F-16 uses a MIL-STD-1553 data bus and was the first aircraft to do so.

References:

- https://www.testandmeasurementtips.com/making-measurements-mil-std-1553-connections/
- https://www.aim-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/aim-ovw1553-u.pdf

Comment: Does any version use dedicated ports in flight control computer for the sensors? For example look at the following reference page 32, figure 20 and the paragraph above it:https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a128624.pdf